# Angular Universal Issue

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have converted my website from angular 6 to Angular Universal..
But now facing an issue
Angular universal is only applied to homepage of the website not the inner pages

Can anyone let me know how to convert inner pages to angular universal so it should be SEO friendly?

**Home Page:**

[image]

**INNER PAGE CODE:**

[image]

Waiting for your response.

Comment: Have you tried hitting CTRL + F5 (Cache refresh)?

Comment: yes i do.. still same

Comment: Any error in the console server side?

Comment: No error.. all is fine.... just home page is getting universal.. check website and see
http://www.dedevelopers.com

Comment: How did you convert your angular 6 project to angular universal? I'm trying to do that now but im afraid of breaking something. Would be nice to get some advice from someone who has already done it. Thanks

Comment: @DreJackson followed some tutorial on medium and helped me.. new on this angular... so try medium tutorial and work on that.. must keep backup of your latest files

Comment: @DreJackson, check this youtube video out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2bfqHOuZSs&t=582s. This guy will essentially walk you through set up for Angular 6, and explain it very well.

Comment: @DeDevelopers can you tell me how you solved this issue Im also facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

This is how angular universal works.

Angular universal use concept of server-side rendering. It means when URL of your angular app hits for the first time. first, the internal server app (Express) will render your requested page. the reason behind this is in your server app javascript is allowed and you can change meta tags dynamically which will improve your SEO.

now if you are using Hashlocation strategy inside your app server will render APP component first so it will not work if you dynamically change meta tags.

My suggestion for you is...

1). if you are using HashLocation strategy then remove it.

2). if you are performing any dom operations (jQuery) or using any browser provided objects (window,localstorage) inside your ngOnInit() move it to ngAfterViewInit().

Answer (score 0):

Agree to remove HashLocation strategy also with a few additional things.

- Make sure your API base URL is configured properly which means that I had a similar issue where node express was picking the API base from the local environment.ts.
- Make sure you have the following lines in the "server" section in angular.json

```
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
   }
 ]
```

- Easy debug technique is commenting your HTTP Client code, and browser code (i.e. window, local storage, all browser global objects)